# How do I find the data segment of Mac OSX executable with Perl?

Tags: perl, macos

I'm writing a tool in Perl that needs to scan for certain binary patterns inside an executable file on a Mac OSX. To avoid getting very many false positives, I want to restrict my search to the data/text segment of the executable, excluding the code segment and a few other things. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using [otool](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html)?

```
-t     Display the contents of the (__TEXT,__text) section.  
-d     Display the contents of the (__DATA,__data) section.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the ELF file format specification.  It contains headers and tables that tell you exactly which segments live where.  Parsing it is tedious but straightforward.